# Cut functionality is not working in shell script

Tags: shell

I have a string like "`iupd=installedupdates`". I need to extract the characters which are before the "`=`".
I'm using the code:

```
PLIST_ITEMS = "iupd=installedupdates"
keyValue = `echo $PLIST_ITEMS| cut -d'=' -f 1`
echo $keyValue
```

keyValue is empty. Please help me by explaining where I'm wrong.

Comment: Try removing the spaces around the assignment operators ("=").

Comment: May i know why the question is down voted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove spaces around the `=` operator:

```
PLIST_ITEMS="iupd=installedupdates"
keyValue=`echo $PLIST_ITEMS| cut -d'=' -f 1`
echo $keyValue
```

Comment: @selva: If I copy'n'paste Amit's code, it works correctly, echoing `iupd`.  If it is not working for you, you need to explain which shell you're using, and which platform you're using it on.  The code shown should work on any shell derived from the Bourne shell (Korn shell, Bash, …); it won't work with shells derived from the C shell (`csh`, `tcsh`).

Comment: @Amit &Jonathan, This code works fine. I have issue at some other places. Thanks for the time.

Answer (score 0):

There's an even easier way, just using Bash without spawning more processes:

```
key=${PLIST_ITEMS%%=*}
```

That chops off the first `=` and everything after, and stores it in `$key`.